# Оформление списка литературы

Tags: общие-вопросы, оформление-текста

Если в сноске указана книга и страницы, то надо ли указывать эти страницы в описании книги в списке литературы?
В случае положительного ответа на заданный вопрос:
Если эта книга указана в нескольких сносках с разными страницами, то в списке литературы эту книгу тоже указать несколько раз или перечислить все страницы в одном описании?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не нужно, в списке литературы указывается общий объём (количество страниц в книге).

https://narfu.ru/agtu/www.agtu.ru/fad08f5ab5ca9486942a52596ba6582elit.html

: http://referatwork.ru/spisok_literaturi/oformlenie_spiska_literaturi_gost_7-1-2003_7-0-5-2008_2014.html